# Org-mode code block evaluation error

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

For some reason, evaluating code blocks stopped working for me.

Example from the manual:

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
   (defun org-xor (a b)
      "Exclusive or."
      (if a (not b) b))
 #+END_SRC
```

Gives now `Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, "(ref:%s)"`. The same happens also for other languages.

Does somebody know what is going on?

I have Org mode version 9.0.1. I believe the problems started when I upgraded (but can't be sure).

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, not knowing your settings and packages...

The api (like function names and signatures) change a bit with org 9. Maybe there is some package using the old api.

To find out, where the error occurs, do

```
M-x toggle-debug-on-error
```

repeat your `C-c C-c`, or how you start your block evaluation, and have a look at the backtrace.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Org-mode version 9, I had the same trouble.

It's solved by recompiling `elpa/org-plus-contrib-******/ob-core.el`
by `M-x byte-compile-file` in my case.

[Org-Mode Evaluation of code disabled · Issue #7641 · syl20bnr/spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7641)